# Calculating velocity variables from transaction logs

Tags: python

I have a table with several million transactions. The table contains a timestamp for the transaction, an amount, and several other properties (e.g., address). For each transaction I want to calculate the count and amount sum of transactions that have happened in a timeframe, e.g., 1 month, with the same, e.g., address.

Here is an example input:

```
+----+---------------------+----------------+--------+
| id | ts                  | address        | amount |
+----+---------------------+----------------+--------+
| 0  | 2016-10-11 00:34:21 | 123 First St.  | 56.20  |
+----+---------------------+----------------+--------+
| 1  | 2016-10-13 02:53:58 | 456 Second St. | 96.19  |
+----+---------------------+----------------+--------+
| 2  | 2016-10-23 02:28:17 | 123 First St.  | 64.65  |
+----+---------------------+----------------+--------+
| 3  | 2016-10-31 07:14:35 | 456 Second St. | 36.38  |
+----+---------------------+----------------+--------+
| 4  | 2016-11-04 09:25:39 | 123 First St.  | 93.65  |
+----+---------------------+----------------+--------+
| 5  | 2016-11-20 22:30:15 | 123 First St.  | 88.39  |
+----+---------------------+----------------+--------+
| 6  | 2016-11-28 09:39:14 | 123 First St.  | 74.40  |
+----+---------------------+----------------+--------+
| 7  | 2016-12-03 17:09:12 | 123 First St.  | 83.13  |
+----+---------------------+----------------+--------+
```

This should output:

```
+----+-------+--------+
| id | count | amount |
+----+-------+--------+
| 0  | 0     | 0.00   |
+----+-------+--------+
| 1  | 0     | 0.00   |
+----+-------+--------+
| 2  | 1     | 56.20  |
+----+-------+--------+
| 3  | 1     | 96.19  |
+----+-------+--------+
| 4  | 2     | 120.85 |
+----+-------+--------+
| 5  | 1     | 64.65  |
+----+-------+--------+
| 6  | 1     | 88.39  |
+----+-------+--------+
| 7  | 2     | 162.79 |
+----+-------+--------+
```

In order to do this, I sorted the table by timestamp and then I'm essentially using queues and dictionaries, but it seems to be running really slow, so I was wondering if there's a better way to do it.

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import Queue
import time

props = [ 'address', ... ]
spans = { '1m': 2629800, ... }

h = [ 'id' ]
for value in [ 'count', 'amount' ]:
    for span in spans:
        for prop in props:
            h.append(span + '_' + prop + '_' + value)

tq = { }
kq = { }
vq = { }
for span in spans:
    tq[span] = Queue.Queue()
    kq[span] = { }
    vq[span] = { }
    for prop in props:
        kq[span][prop] = Queue.Queue()
        vq[span][prop] = { }

with open('transactions.csv', 'r') as csvin, open('velocities.csv', 'w') as csvout:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvin)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvout, h)
    writer.writeheader()
    for i in reader:
        o = { 'id': i['id'] }
        ts = time.mktime(time.strptime(i['ts'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        for span in spans:
            while not tq[span].empty() and ts > tq[span].queue[0] + spans[span]:
                tq[span].get()
                for prop in props:
                    key = kq[span][prop].get()
                    vq[span][prop][key].get()
                    if vq[span][prop][key].empty():
                        del vq[span][prop][key]
            tq[span].put(ts)
            for prop in props:
                kq[span][prop].put(i[prop])
                if not i[prop] in vq[span][prop]:
                    vq[span][prop][i[prop]] = Queue.Queue()
                o[span + '_' + prop + '_count'] = vq[span][prop][i[prop]].qsize()
                o[span + '_' + prop + '_amount'] = sum(vq[span][prop][i[prop]].queue)
                vq[span][prop][i[prop]].put(float(i['auth']))
        writer.writerow(o)
        csvout.flush()
```

I also tried replacing `vq[span][prop]` with a RB-trees but the performance was even worse.

Answer (score 0):

Either I fundamentally misunderstand what you're trying to do, or you do, because your code is *vastly* more complicated (not complex, **complicated**) than it needs to be if you're doing what you say you're doing.

```
import csv
from collections import namedtuple, defaultdict, Counter
from datetime import datetime

Span = namedtuple('Span', ('start', 'end'))

month_span = Span(start=datetime(2016, 1, 1), end=datetime(2016, 1, 31))
counts = defaultdict(Counter)
amounts = defaultdict(Counter)
with open('transactions.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        timestamp = datetime.strptime(row['ts'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        if month_span.start < timestamp < month_span.end:  # or <=
            # You do some checking for properties. If you *will* always
            # have these columns, you *should* just use ``row['count']``
            # and ``row['amount']``
            counts[month_span][row['address']] += int(row.get('count', 0))
            amount[month_span][row['address']] += float(row.get('amount', 0.00))
print(counts)
print(amounts)
```

Note that you're *still* operating, as you say, over "several million transactions". That's going to take a while no matter which way you turn it because you're doing the same thing *several million times*. If you want to see where your current code is spending all it's time, you can [profile it](https://www.huyng.com/posts/python-performance-analysis). I find that the [line profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) is easy to use and works well.

Chances are, because you're doing what you're doing a million times, you're not going to be able to speed this up much, without dropping to a lower level language, e.g. Cython, C, or C++. That will speed some things up, but it will definitely be a lot harder to write the code.

Comment: I may not have been clear enough. When I process a line in the CSV (a transaction), the count and amount must be those of all of the previous transactions in the timeframe, e.g., all transactions that happened within the month prior to the transaction (and that share the property, e.g., have the same address).

Comment: To clarify, as an example, this means that if the current transaction is dated `2016-03-01 10:33:11` and has address `123 Main St`, then the output would reflect all transactions that happened up to 2629800 seconds before that and had the same address.

Comment: If you're grouping by a second dimension, it's pretty easy - just use `defaultdict(Counter)` - I've updated my example.

Comment: The timeframe is constantly rolling when you move on to the next transaction (i.e., 1 month back from the current transaction's timestamp), it's not fixed at the beginning. I added an example input/output, maybe that makes it clearer.

Comment: This code should be *plenty* to get you down the road. If you'd like me to write your code for you, I have a consulting rate.